# $\int_0^\infty0.5e^{-|x|}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is first time I'm solving integral with absolute value and I have issue with example of this integral. Here is my solution, but textbook says it should be 1 so any input is greatly appreciated. I used $u$-substitution:
$$u=-|x|$$
$$\int_0^\infty0.5e^{-|x|}\,dx=-0
.5\int_0^{-\infty}e^u\,du=0.5$$

Comment: Are you sure the question is not supposed to be:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 0.5e^{-|x|}~dx$$
If so, the answer is indeed $1$. The definite integral you wrote on the title indeed evaluates to $0.5$.

Comment: |x| is positive on your interval so $ |x| =x$

Comment: Are you sure the original integral wasn't from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?  That gives the desired answer and, as it stands, there is no point to the absolute value.

Comment: This is correct integral...so it is probably mistake and integral should range from $\infty$ to  ${-\infty}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $x\ge0$, $ |x|=x$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} 0,5{e^{-|x|}} dx = 0,5\int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-x}} dx = -0,5\lim_{M \to \infty}(e^{-M}-e^0)=-0,5(0-1)=0,5$$
If $x\in (-\infty$, $\infty)$, value converges to $1$, since $e^{-|x|}$ is even:
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 0,5{e^{-|x|}} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} 0,5{e^{x}} dx+ \int_{0}^{\infty} 0,5{e^{-x}} dx=  2\int_{0}^{\infty} 0,5{e^{-x}} dx $$